# Distill y_true and y_pred from a confusion matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a confusion matrix that I generated via Scikit-Learn. I was wondering if it were possible to reverse engineer it and get the `y_true` and `y_pred` given only the confusion matrix in Python. If there is nothing built in (like in Scikit-Learn), would someone mind providing a code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to reverse-engineer `y_true` and `y_pred` from a given confusion matrix, as the confusion matrix is invariant to permutations of the elements of  `y_pred` and `y_true`.

An easy example would be the following: Consider `y_true=[0,1]` and `y_pred=[1, 0]`. The confusion matrix is exactly the same than for `y_true=[1, 0]` and `y_pred=[0, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

See solution below.

Note that @TobiasWindisch is correct that such a solution is usually not unique w.r.t. permutations of items.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

def get_ytrue_ypred(cm):
    y_true = []
    y_pred = []
    # NOTE: `confusion_matrix` returns a CM, where CM_ij represents count of items
    # which belong to true class i and are predicted as class j.
    for true_idx in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for pred_idx in range(cm.shape[1]):
            cnt = cm[true_idx, pred_idx]
            y_true.extend([true_idx] * cnt)
            y_pred.extend([pred_idx] * cnt)

    return np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)

def test_get_ytrue_ypred():       
    cm = np.array(
        [
            [99,1,2],
            [3,55,4],
            [5,6,17],
        ]
    )

    y_true, y_pred = get_ytrue_ypred(cm)

    cm2 = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(cm, cm2)
```